# Geodesics in free homotopy classes and the fundamental group

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the upper half-plane and $\Gamma$ be a cocompact, torsion-free Fuchsian group. The quotient space $X=\Gamma\backslash \mathcal{H}$ is a smooth closed Riemann surface and there is a well-known identification between (conjugacy-classes) of hyperbolic transformations $\gamma\in\Gamma$ and closed geodesics $g_\gamma$ on $X$. At the same time, the group $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,p)$, where $p\in X$, by a standard result of algebraic topology. The fundamental group $\pi_1(X,p)$ consists of closed loops passing through $p$ and it is known that in any free homotopy class of such a loop there exists a unique closed geodesic.

Now my question is as follows: Is it possible to choose an isomorphism $\phi:\Gamma\to\pi_1(X)$ such that the unique geodesic in the free homotopy class of $\phi(\gamma)$ is given by $g_\gamma$? I somehow always assumed that this is possible, but I was unable to find such a result online or in a few books a checked. I would be grateful for any hints and references.

Comment: $\Gamma$ itself is a group, so the conjugacy classes are defined there, and $g_\gamma$ is the corresponding closed geodesic.  So it is not clear what role your $\phi$ plays.  Certainly an isomorphism between groups preserves conjugacy classes.